# How to create new project inside a homestead virtual machine?

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

Inside my homestead virtual machine, I ran `laravel new test`. Now I got a fresh laravel project in my homestead virtual machine.

Then I configured the `Homestead.yaml`:

```
- map: ~/work/test # an empty dirctory
  to: /home/vagrant/test
```

Finally, I ran `vagrant reload --provision`.

Oops, I found `home/vagrant/test` is an empty directory now!

It seems vagrant only sync data from **Host Machine** to **Homestead Virtual Machine**, and I just want to create a project inside a 
**Homestead Virtual Machine**, then sync it to **Homestead Virtual Machine**.

Is there any way I can achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

`/home/vagrant/test` is directory which is in your machine and not on your VM

if you want to create project then create in this directory run the following command

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel ./
```

This command will create the project in your current directory after this run

```
vagrant reload --provision
```

after provision run

```
vagrant ssh
cd ~/work/test
ls
```

now you can see your all the files of newly created project.

Comment: Yeah, I know that, but I just want to know how to create a project inside a VM, then sync it to my Host Machine?

Comment: @Sayakiss if you create any file in synced directory it will automatically synced to your machine